# Mondrian support for nosql like mongodb

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

Does Mondrian support nosql db like mongodb in the current version.  I read some blogs and bugs related to the same.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mondrian does not directly support MongoDB at the moment. MongoDB does not have a JDBC implementation.

There are a few options. One of them can be setup if you have access to a Pentaho Data Integration server. You can use a [thin JDBC implementation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/eai/the+thin+kettle+jdbc+driver) which will allow Mondrian to access a SQL to Mongo bridge.

There are certainly other ways to set this up, since there are a lot of data federation engines out there.

Answer (score 2):

please read the following Blog from Julian Hyde, creator of Mondrian

http://julianhyde.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/improvements-to-optiqs-mongodb-adapter.html

Here you can see Julian have been working on a new approach that converts even complex SQL queries into MongoDB Queries behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly as far as I know.  Maybe someone is working on a dialect, is that even possible..?  Interesting question though...  May be worth linking the blogs you found so far?

One solution however could be to use the kettle jdbc driver, this driver works with mondrian and then the other end can be any ETL process. So you could use a mongodb input step etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is Apache Drill. You can query MongoDB through standard SQL and Drill has a JDBC driver. So maybe it is possible that Mondrian uses this driver.

Uwe